# Can I auto-detect which serial port where a specific device is connected?

Tags: java, applet, serial-port

I'm building a java applet which needs to read data from a serial connected device. At this point I'm displaying a dropdown which shows all the serial COM ports from the laptop/workstation. The user has to manually select the designated port on which the device is connected to.

Most of the times the users won't know the right port number or won't know how to find this out. So i was wondering if there is a way to do some sort of auto-detection that selects the right device? Is there any possible way to get the id/model/name of the devices connected to the serial ports?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what library are you using for serial communication?

Comment: I'm using the jSSC library which you can find here http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such "integrated" feature for device identification.

One could actively try out each port with the necessary parameters and send/listen for an ID-command your device supports, **BUT** I would not recommend it.

When other devices are connection besides yours, the transfer of strings or change of parameters for a port where a different device than yours is connected to, can lead to very errornous behavior